# Uses of the definite article (the) in generic noun phrases

Tags: definite-article, generic-noun-phrases

I was reading a paragraph about lions and I came up with a question about **the definite article (the)**.

Let me tell you first what I know about it.

> 1->We use *the* before a singular noun (when we are sure about the noun.
>    And the listener and the speaker both know about it).
>
> 2->We use *the* before a plural noun (again when we are sure about the noun,
>   and we are not talking generally).

So, my question is why does the writer use *the* here as we are not talking about any specific lion or lions. We are talking generally.

**The Paragraph:**

> Living in **the** grasslands, scrub, and open woodlands of sub-Saharan
>   Africa, **the** lion is the second largest cat in the world. It is dwarfed
>   slightly by **the** tiger, which is closely related and has a very similar
>   body type.

**Can we re-write the paragraph something like this:**

> Living in grasslands, scrub, and open woodlands of sub-Saharan Africa,
>   lions are the second largest cat in the world. They are dwarfed
>   slightly by tigers, they are closely related and has a very similar
>   body type.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html. To summarize it, the definite generic (*the lion*) refers to the prototype of a species, and the plural generic (*lions*) refers to the norm of a species. In this case the species of the lions living there, I believe.

Comment: In your rewrite, the end of the second sentence should be "[...] and *have* a very similar body type." Since you are referring to tigers in the plural, the verb should be plural as well.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, your rewrite is acceptable.

As for your confusion, it looks like you might have a case of DAMS (Definite Article Meaning Syndrome), a relatively common affliction that often affects English learners. Its chief symptom is *confusion*, generally caused by the erroneous belief that definite articles are only used for things **previously referred to and specified in a narrative or conversation**.

However, there are *other* uses of the definite article – ones that don't seem to get as much attention in ESL classes. For example, the word “the” can also be used:

- to refer to things that are **unique** (*The Mona Lisa hangs in the Louvre.*)
- to make a **generalized reference to something** (*Bob plays the piano*.)
- with adjectives, to **refer to a group of people** (*This is another tax break for the rich*.)
- to indicate that there is **enough of something** (*She will bake a pie, if she has the ingredients*.)

In the passage you quote, the author elected to use the definite article to make a **generalized reference** to the flora and fauna of Africa: grassy woodlands, lions and tigers. The wording would only seem strange to someone afflicted with DAMS.

This is worth mentioning, too; under its entry for **the**, NOAD lists:

> used with a singular noun to indicate that it represents a whole species or class : *they placed the African elephant on their endangered list*.

---

(Disclaimer: DAMS is an acronym I just made up for the purpose of this answer. It was intended to be humorous. However, this isn't the first time I've witnessed this confusion; I've encountered it several times on both ELL and ELU.)

Comment: I believe that in the latest diagnostics, which are learner- rather than pedagog-centered, this has been reclassified as *Definite Article Meaning Nonstability Incomprehension Trauma*.

Comment: It was useful, but I didn't get **generalized reference to something**, it was good if you had explained it more, you mean a reference to something regarding a general scope, for example the lion, not any other animal?

Comment: @Ahmad - _The cheetah is the fastest animal on the planet_. (That's not a *particular* cheetah; that refers to all cheetahs in general.). _The learner might often struggle with this concept_. (Again, that's not necessarily referring to a particular learner, but to all learners in general.)

Comment: @J.R. What is its difference with *cheetah is the fastest animal on the planet* or *cheetahs are fastest animals on the planet*

Comment: @Ahmed - You wouldn't say the first without a "the" in front of _cheetah_, and you wouldn't say the second without a "the" in front of _fastest_. Other that that, though, it's just two ways of saying the same thing, so... _The cheetah is the fastest animal on the planet_. _Cheetahs are the fastest animals on the planet._

Comment: @J.R. Some sources say that "a" can be used for generalization as well. E.g. "A man needs friends". How to define which article use for which cases? https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/indefinite-article-and

Comment: Why native speakers don't suffer from DAMS (even at a very young age)?

Comment: Why do you think so ? They usually do a little. Especially, until their teen age. But, the domestic learners have got such an advantage as watching local television and some more useful such-like.