# Definite article usage from exercise

Tags: articles

I'm learning articles and doing some exercises.

Here are my problem sentences:

> A: What is a "capital city"?
>
> B: Well, a "capital city" is the political center of a country.

My question is about 'the' in the second sentence.
I'm don't see here any 'definiteness' of the center. From my point of view it is as  indefinite as the country and city words.

Comment: A center is unique. A circle can have only one center: that's part of the very definition (and utility) of the concept *center*. By analogy, "*the* political center" of a country lies at the very heart of that country's power structure. Washington, D.C. is *the* political center of the United States. New York City is its financial center. L.A. is its (shudder) cultural center. And so on.

Comment: @Dan LA is a cultural centre? Presumably you mean in the same sense as a bowl of yoghurt is a cultural centre?

Comment: But the capital is unique too. I don't see here any differences.

Comment: @Janus, I wish SE had a comment hall of fame, just so I could put that in it.

Comment: @Nosturion The capital city of a country is unique. The notion of a city being capital is not unique—note how it says “capital city” in quotes. It's talking about the concept of a capital city (not of any specific country, but in general). It could just as well have said, “What is a ‘political centre’?” A capital city is a political centre. The capital city of the US is the political centre of the US. That means it's also a political centre.

Comment: Another  way to put it: in the US, there is only *one* city with the political clout of Washington, D.C., and that's Washington, D.C. There is *no other city* in the US with the political clout of Washington D.C.. In that way, Washington D.C. is *unique*. Therefore, Washington is ***the** political center* of the United States

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: You might not like the culture (or yogurt, for that matter), but yes, L.A. is **a** center of western culture - bordering on world culture. It has been so, and increasingly so, for more than 60 years. Yes, that is only a historical instant. (And who knows how long it will continue?) But the transformative effect in that short time has been extraordinary. Any of us might choose to say *Alas!* (ou *Helas !*), but 'tis a fact of life. Fini, la Belle Epoque. (Or at least it seems to be taking a timeout.)

Comment: @DanBron: No, a center is not unique. If it were, it would be **the** center.  The center of a particular circle or sphere is unique. Like a maximum or a minimum, a center can be relative. Put differently if you prefer, different spheres can have different centers.  Everything is not concentric. And yes, I know you realize this, precisely because of the examples you gave - of different things with different centers.

Comment: For each country, there is one, unique political center. So we use _the_ when the context is a single country, because it's unique in that context. So London is _a_ capital city, but it's _the_ capital city of England.

Comment: How about a country where the capital is _not_ the political centre? Like, the government, parliament etc, are in City A, but the capital is city B?

Answer (score 1):

We use the definite article *the* when we're referring to something specific or unique. While there are many political centers in general because there are many countries, the prepositional phrase *of a country* sets the context to being a single, although unspecified, country. For that country there's only one political center, so we use *the* rather than *a*.

As another example, we could say:

> A nose is *the* organ in the center of a face.

Answer (score 0):

By using *the* instead of *a*, we can readily see that, in general, countries only have **one*** capital city.

Note that the definite article (i.e., the word "the") has several uses outside of "definiteness". Using "the" instead of "a" can indicate *uniqueness*, *generalization*, *sufficiency*, or *members of a group*. (I wrote more about this in my answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/uses-of-the-definite-article-the/22650#22650).)

---

*Bolivia is sometimes said to be a noted exception, though some say that would be [erroneous](http://www.boliviabella.com/capital.html). (Nonetheless, this conversation is about grammar, not geography.)