# Using "the" for mentioned general terms

Tags: zero-article

I am not sure if the title describes my question here, but I am not sure whether I need to use the definite article in this context:

> Qualitative research instruments include interviews, focus groups,
>   reviews, and observation. **[The] Interviews** include either a series of
>   structured questions, or allowing subjects to speak out their
>   experience. **[The] Focus groups** allow gathering observations from a group of
>   people who have similar properties. For instance, a group of men over
>   40. They give their opinions of the given topic. **[The] review** is done to collect scholarly written literature or other published materials to
>   find attitudes towards a subject.

Do I need to use "the" in the bold sections in the paragraph above? If so, can you please explain the reason?

Comment: This looks a little like [Uses of the definite article (the)](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/22647), although it's not quite a duplicate.

Comment: Just my gut feeling.  I would not use the definite article, but I would write Reviews. It is clear that you explain the aforementioned terms. And in such explanations of terms a definite article is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  You are indeed referring to specific interviews, focus groups and reviews, i.e. the ones that you have already mentioned.  However, in this case, you will draw attention to that fact by using the definite article, and you won't if you do not.  You may choose either.  Personally, in this case, I would not use them.

One other point: I would change **review** to the plural **reviews** to make it consistent with the others.