# 'Question 1' or 'the question 1'?

Tags: word-usage, articles, definite-article

(this may seem to be a simple question for native speakers as I think they don't even think about it, but it's not so clear for me)

In formal language, should it be written with or without "the" in the following cases?:

1) "(The) question 1 was asked in order to identify..."

2) "Answers to (the) question 1 were..."

3) In the label below the figure: "(The) question 1"

Comment: No, we don't use articles with "numbered" noun phrases like "room 102", "question 1", "page 314", etc. Related: **[Why do we not use the definite article in “Where can I find the room 401?”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73709/why-do-we-not-use-the-definite-article-in-where-can-i-find-the-room-401)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When cardinal numbers follow nouns as in your example, it is not necessary to use the definite article *the* before the noun as Question 1 itself is unique and you don't need to specify it further. There is only one *Question 1* in your test.

The same rule applies when you indicate a hotel room number. You don't say "the room number 505, you just say "room number 505" as there is only one room that has this number in the hotel.

Answer (score 0):

***Question 1*** in these contexts is effectively a "proper noun" (it identifies one specific thing).

For the same reason why we don't refer to the<sup>1</sup> OP as ***the*** Riko, we don't use a definite article when referencing ***Question 1***.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that ***OP*** normally stands for *Original Poster* (the person who originally posted the question). Sometimes it's *Original Post* (the question itself), but I don't usually use it in that sense myself.

In this particular context, it's a matter of intended *nuance* whether to include ***the*** before ***OP***. It depends on whether the writer is thinking "locally". Within the context of a single question, ***OP*** identifies a single individual (so in this case, ***OP*** corresponds to the one-and-only ***Riko***, and *doesn't* require an article).

But if the writer is thinking in broader terms (where ***OP*** more "generically" references *anyone* who posts a question), the definite article *is* required, as he's talking about a *specific* OP (*this* one, Riko).