# "the vector v contains" vs. "vector v contains" - should one use the definite article here?

Tags: articles

Assume in a text we have two vectors v and z. Each vector contains m elements.
Which one is correct:

1- " the vector v contains ..."

2- " vector v contains ..."

Comment: We'd need a *full* context (complete sentence, plus some indication of what text came before it) to give a definitive answer on this point. But for most purposes it's probably sufficient to say the article is ***optional*** in such constructions (but most people probably *wouldn't* include it).

Comment: Related: [Why do we not use the definite article in “Where can I find the room 401?”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73709/why-do-we-not-use-the-definite-article-in-where-can-i-find-the-room-401)

Comment: More context is needed.  #1 would be used at the beginning or possibly middle of a sentence, and #2 might be used in the middle of a sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would, in most cases, not use "the" in this example. That is because "vector v" is a unique object of which there is not more that one. Because it is unique, it doesn't need articles to distinguish it from a crowd (that crowd doesn't exist). You can still use "the" if you wanted to, but most people would not. If the vector did not have a specific indicator (like the name "v" given to this one), then the articles would apply, as a vector can take on many different forms and properties.