# The protein part of the substance is identical to natural human interferon beta-1a

Tags: articles

> The protein part of the substance is identical to natural human interferon beta-1a.

Should there be **the** before "natural ... 2b"?

> The protein part of the substance is identical to **the** natural human interferon beta-1a.

There are two adjectives: natural and human. On the other hand, there's the designation "beta-1a". Should we then omit the article, like we omit it in "[Room 301](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/73709/2127)"?

Comment: The article is omitted not because *interferon beta-1a* is a name but because it is a substance.

Comment: @StoneyB - but when I imagine "interferon beta-1a", it looks like an individual thing, a long protein. And it is compared with "the protein part", which is also a structural unit, not an uncountable substance.

Comment: But it's part of a substance; and chemical analysis is carried out on samples, not individual molecules.

Comment: We don't always omit *the* in *the Room 301*, or *401*, [as this answer explains](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/75676/29924).

Comment: @AlanCarmack - nice! I totally overlooked that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The protein part of the substance is identical to natural human interferon beta-1a

This sentence is equivalent to

> Synthetic vanillin is identical to natural vanillin.

In both cases, we are talking about a substance, which is uncountable

If we want to talk about an individual molecule, we would have to say

> A molecule of Synthetic vanillin is identical to a molecule of natural vanillin

or

> The molecular structure of synthetic vanillin is identical to that of natural vanillin.

Similarly, in your sentence, you would have to say

> The molecular structure of the protein part of the substance is identical to that of natural human interferon beta-1a