# "in the Chapter 7" or "in Chapter 7"

Tags: usage, definite-article

Which of the following sentence is correct?

> As mentioned in **the** Chapter 7,

or

> As mentioned in Chapter 7

I do not think "the" is necessary as it clearly mentions about chapter number.

Comment: Actually "Chapter 7" is the name of the chapter, so no article is used. "As mentioned in *the* seventh chapter." would be OK though.

Comment: Related: [Where can I find Room 401?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73709/why-do-we-not-use-the-definite-article-in-where-can-i-find-the-room-401)

Comment: @ARYF - Book titles and chapter headings are treated as proper nouns, as every elementary English textbook and instructional website makes clear! Did you do any research?

Comment: I don't know why, but Chapter 7 and Chapter 13 seem to be mentioned quite often lately. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By 'numbering' it, you are making a *definite reference* to that chapter. It is seventh. Thus, it'd serve like a proper noun. It'll go without any article.

> As mentioned in *Chapter 7*

However, *'the'* is possible when it does not serve as a *proper noun*

> As mentioned in *the seventh chapter*

Or...

> Have you read *the chapter on Skeleton System?*