# Should one use the definite article before "peptide LC 10-28"?

Tags: articles, zero-article, terminology

> The examination of the mass-spectra showed an absence of the oxidized form of **peptide LC 10-28**, thus we determined only the contents of oxidized peptides HC 150-156 and HC 118-140.

I'm not sure about the use of articles here. Does the ["where is room 301](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/73709/2127)" rule apply here?

"LC 10-28" is a kind of code indicating the position of the peptide in the light chain of the antibody molecule. Looks like the number "301" in "room 301".

Or does it work like a proper name here, necessitating the use of the definite article?

> The examination of the mass-spectra showed an absence of the oxidized form of **the peptide LC 10-28**, thus we determined only the contents of oxidized peptides HC 150-156 and HC 118-140.

A peptide is not exactly like a "room", this is one thing that confuses me. Peptides differ in their length and amino acid composition.

Comment: Either version is idiomatic, but it seems to me that the tradition in scientific writing is to omit articles whenever possible. I have my own theory about the origin of this tradition, but anyone who reads scientific literature will have noticed that the articles are in short supply.

Comment: Evidence from Ngram suggests the use of the article:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=form+of+peptide%2Cform+of+the+peptide&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cform%20of%20peptide%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cform%20of%20the%20peptide%3B%2Cc0 - but I agree that both versions may fit.

Comment: The rule here is analogous to "The Eyewitness News team spoke with *swimmer Michael Phelps*".

Answer (score 1):

With things that have generic labels instead of names, the zero article should definitely be used:

- Room 301
- Chapter 11
- Orbital 1s
- Level 1

Even things that have names are often used with zero article:

- Queen Elizabeth
- USS Enterprise
- Planet Earth
- Mount Everest

The definite article is sometimes used when one wants to clarify which of several things with the same name is referred to:

- I'm talking about the planet Venus, not the goddess.

So if "LC 10-28" can have various meanings in the context, then using "the peptide LC 10-28" makes sense. But if it's a unique label, the article "the" seems redundant.