# "room 7" "page 44": Why no def. article "the"?

Tags: zero-article

Can anyone simply explain why the following expressions do not take the definite article “the”? I know (as a native speaker) that no article is needed; just looking for the precise grammar functioning here.

> Room 7

(*Bob is in Room 7*)

> Page 44

(*Please open to page 44.*)

Comment: In context, there is only one room 7 or page 44. so the indefinite article would be inapt; since the number completely specifies the item, the definite article would be redundant.

Comment: @deadrat Thanks. Yes. In terms of meaning, “Room 7” is already uniquely identified, and so no article is needed. But I’m wondering if a more grammar-based explanation is possible, rather than involving semantics such as “uniquely identified,” as a simple rule of thumb for non-natives.

Comment: The main reason is that this is English, and articles are not used in those contexts.

Comment: [related question on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73709/why-do-we-not-use-the-definite-article-in-where-can-i-find-the-room-401)