# Countable nouns and determiners

Tags: grammar, articles, determiners, countable-nouns

Is using the definite article here in this sentence incorrect? If yes, what's its reason? The word 'chapter' is a count noun.

*Have you finished the chapter eight of your novel book?*

Comment: @ColleenV: Why is it off-topic? It's a grammar issue. I wish you knew the answer and would state it here instead of simply making a great question off-topic!

Comment: The close reason for proofreading does include an explanation: "Questions asking for someone to **find and correct errors** or **improve the phrasing** are considered requests for proofreading and are off-topic. Please edit your question to focus on **something in particular** that you are unsure about; if that's not possible, see [websites for proofreading](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/alternative-websites-for-proofreading) instead."  If you'd like to discuss whether proofreading questions should be on-topic, please head to [meta].

Comment: OK, I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't say:

> <s>Have you finished **the chapter eight** of your novel</s>?

You can say:

> Have you finished **chapter eight** of your novel?
>
> Have you finished **the eighth chapter** of your novel?
>
> Have you finished **eight chapters** of your novel?
>
> Have you finished **the first eight chapters** of your novel?

(Some of those differ slightly in meaning, but I include them for comparison.)

"The eighth chapter", "the fifth book", "the second volume", "the fourth page", "the second series" take the definite article.  But "chapter eight", "book five", "volume two", "page four", "series two" don't.

You could also have a table in a restaurant called "table 7", or an airport terminal called "terminal 2", a runway called "runway 1", or a gate called "gate 9".

The numeral after the noun causes it to refer to a specific chapter (etc) and causes the definite article to become impossible.

See also: [Why do we not use the definite article in "Where can I find <s>the</s> Room 401?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73709/why-do-we-not-use-the-definite-article-in-where-can-i-find-the-room-401)

Comment: "chapter eight", "book five", "volume two", "page four", "series two", "table 7", "terminal 2", "terminal 2", "gate 9". Good examples. Thanks. (+1) But why did you drop the word *book* in the sentence?

Comment: We just don't say "novel book".  We'd call it either a "novel" or a "book".  We'd only say "novel book" if we were using the adjective "novel" (= new, innovative) rather than the noun "novel" (= a work of prose fiction of reasonably great length).