# My favorite fruit is grape/grapes

Tags: uncountable-nouns

Let's say you are asked by your teacher what is your favorite fruit, then you say:

> "my favorite fruit is **grape/grapes**"

Which one is correct in terms of the general selection according to what I have just written here? Because I have just seen a website which he/she exemplified "**[my favorite fruits are grapes](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/331111)**" this confuses me a bit now.

Comment: You should use *grapes* though, since there is no pronoun. In any case it is usually considered plural, since if you picture the fruit it probably won't be one grape. "My favorite flavor is grape." would be OK.

Comment: The accepted answer to [Why do we say “I love cake” but “I love cars”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/129728/) might be helpful. [(The?) Lions in the zoo are very aggressive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/123980/) might also be interesting to you, although I don't think it helps answer *this* question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to answer your teacher (and eliminate your quandary) is to simply say:

> Grapes are my favorite fruit.

However, that's merely a way to dodge your question, not confront it head-on. What should we do when we start our answer with:

> My favorite fruit...

First, let's pick a different fruit. One way to construct the sentence is to use an article:

> My favorite fruit is the nectarine.
>   My favorite fruit is a plum.

Alternatively, we could use no article, but then we need to decide what to do with the verb. As a discussion on Quora says:

> As “fruit” is both a countable and uncountable noun, it can be singular or plural. So while it is a choice between “My favorite fruit is apples,” or “My favorite fruit is apple,” the only correct choice is “My favorite fruit is apples” because you would need some kind of determiner such as a number or article to precede the singular object.

This is made even trickier by the fact that we seldom refer to a *grape* in the singular but usually talk about grapes in the plural.

So, if I had to start with, "My favorite...," I would probably say:

> My favorite fruit is grapes.

It's not ungrammatical, although it might sound ungrammatical because grapes sounds like a plural noun, right next to the singular *is*.

Evidently, this construct has vexed others before. (See [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/favorite-fruit-is-apple-vs-is-an-apple.3116357/) or [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/favourite-fruit-s-is-are.1462791/) conversation on Word Reference, or [this poll](https://www.usingenglish.com/poll/243.php) on UE, for example.)

Perhaps comedian [Demetri Martin](http://izquotes.com/quotes-pictures/quote-my-favorite-fruit-is-grapes-because-with-grapes-you-always-get-another-chance-cause-you-know-demetri-martin-120582.jpg) said it best:

> My favorite fruit is grapes. Because with grapes, you always get another chance.

Comment: I got what you're saying here, thx. It seems this is a very complex question I say, right? The answers provided here are not grammar book based, because, I think, there hasn't specific rule especially on this one yet, rather 'polls', personal preference, experience wise are the main answers here. Still a very horrible answer to avoid, especially me, which I might get wronged if a native who may have a menial experience about this particularly. My oh my...

Answer (score -1):

**In everyday English** (not biology, botany or Biblical contexts), **the word fruit is never plural**.

And, if you are talking about your favorite fruit, you would say or write:

**My favorite fruit is** grapes or bananas. Fruit is singular grammatically even if the meaning is plural, as in:

I love tropical fruit like pineapples, bananas and mangoes.

Have a fruitful day! :)

Comment: “Never” is a strong word. Some counterexamples: The American Heart Association urges people to [eat more **fruits** and vegetables](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/HealthyLiving/WeightManagement/LosingWeight/Eat-More-Fruits-and-Vegetables_UCM_320237_Article.jsp#.Wrb-qrzUu-I). And I don’t think [this article’s](http://www.mashed.com/69014/fruits-you-should-shouldnt-be-eating/) headline – ***8 fruits you should be eating*** – would sound right with the singular form. _Fruit_ is a tricky word, and I don’t think this answer – as worded – gives the most accurate guidance to learners.

Comment: One more interesting counterexample: _Open from 8 am to 1 pm daily, the market has plenty of **fruits**, vegetables, meats, eggs, flowers, pastries and more._ While the word _fruit_ in the singular form could work in that sentence, I think the plural form works better, given that every other word in the list is pluralized. [Interesting Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tropical+fruit+like%2Ctropical+fruits+like&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=6). “My favorite fruits are grapes and bananas” is also grammatical.

Comment: @J. R.  You did not read my answer carefully enough. In ***every day*** conversation (about fruit) the plural is never used. Just because some SEO article uses the plural doesn't reveal anything at all. The internet is a junk playground. The problem with ngrams and google hits is that they are meaningless without human experience and super-vision.

Comment: I read your answer plenty carefully. And the links I’ve provided do not point to “junk playground” sites. [This article](https://www.wsj.com/articles/fruit-veggies-and-how-to-depict-the-universe-1510763961) provides an interesting take – the word “fruit” is used nine times, while the word “fruits” is used only once, showing that “fruit” is indeed used much more often than not, but “never” is still too strong a word for an ELL answer to be accurate.

Comment: @J.R. No one ever says in everyday conversation: I'm going to the super market to buy fruits. Articles re fruit and vegetables are "semi-scientific", at best dietary advice from professionals. I can think of ***no context where I would say fruit with a s in terms of eating fruit or buying fruit or liking***.

Comment: You’re right, I wouldn’t say that remark about the supermarket. However, a sentence like, “Seasonal fruits are always popular,” doesn’t seem beyond the realm of possibility in everyday conversation.

Comment: If we consult a corpus of spontaneous spoken English conversation such as the Fisher English corpus, we find that both *fruit* and *fruits* are common, although *fruit* is slightly more common.  I found 179 results for *fruit* and 111 results for *fruits* in Fisher.  The claim that the plural is not used in everyday conversation appears to be simply false.

Comment: I can almost use 'fruit' and 'fruits' accurately in every sentence that I construct. This uncountable noun 'fruit' is the base of it, but there are some alterations when your context such as different groups of fruit(in a container) is the thing you have to say. ANYWAY, I just asked specifically the 'my favorite fruit is GRAPE/GRAPES' to clarify if GRAPE or GRAPES is the right answer. I'm not asking about fruit/fruits(it's not in bold letters right)

Comment: _Americans are nibbling more whole fruits, nuts and seeds. Throw in vegetables and fruits from salsa and you have a healthy balanced diet. As its name suggests, it [fructose] is found mainly in fruits. Export of fruits and nuts provided about 40% of the country's foreign exchange. The cranberry is one of only three fruits native to North America. A panda goes into a bar, eats shoots and leaves. Nothing remarkable about that nowadays, since half the bars in the world seem to be making drinks out of shoots, leaves, roots, herbs, spices, fruits, vegetables and insects._ (from The Economist)

Comment: In everyday English, *fruits* means different kinds of fruit. So you would say *my favorite fruit is grapes*, but *my favorite fruits are grapes and strawberries*. If you say *my favorite fruit is grapes and strawberries*, it sounds to me like you're saying your favorite is a mixture of grapes and strawberries.

Comment: Would you like fruit for dessert? (bananas,oranges,or whatever.) Do you like tropical fruit? Pineapples and papayas? The question is: My favorite fruit is grapes. Not: are grapes. That's the point here.