# Proper use of "the" in American English

Tags: articles, american-english

I read in a grammar textbook that when people want to talk about general phenomena they shouldn’t use “the”. For example:

> *They took him to hospital*.

Here the speaker doesn’t mean a specific hospital. Then it is mentioned that in American English, “the” is used for general phenomena too. So:

> *They took him to the hospital*.

Here also, the speaker doesn’t mean a specific hospital.

I wonder if it is a general rule in American English? For example which of the following is correct in American English?

> *I have to be at the airport by 5PM*. (Not a specific airport, but the general meaning of airport.)

or

> *I have to be at airport by 5PM*. (Not a specific airport, but the general meaning of airport.)

Comment: The speaker is thinking of a specific hospital though, even if just the closest. Same with airport.

Comment: Closely related: [Usage of articles before the noun 'hospital'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44588) and [go to university or go to the university](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140982) and [What is this case of using “the” in front of a noun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/177219)

Comment: Re the last example: in BrE we don't say "I have to be at hospital by 5pm." Like **court**, **hospital** is an *event* as much as a place.

Comment: "I wonder if it is a general role in American English?" Do you mean "rule"? They are homophones for some people, but not in general.

Comment: Thank you, corrected it.

Comment: How interesting. I was unaware this was a Br/Am English difference; in my (English) English, I can happily say "I went to school/hospital/sea/prison/church/bed/town/court/university/college." Which can't you say in Am English?

Comment: @Showsni, of those, *hospital* is the only example where "the" is required.

Comment: @Showsni - In addition to *hospital*, I would also add *sea* and *university* to the list requiring *the*.

Comment: @Justin Agreed on *university*, but not *sea*.  With *the*, "*I went to the sea*" generally refers to a specific (probably nearby) body of water (and also could be just spending a day at the beach, not necessarily involving a boat), while "*I went to sea*" means I went sailing without referencing any specific body of water - but you do actually have to get away from the shore for that one.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Oh, right, I agree with that. I was thinking of going to the beach. "A sailor went to sea" sounds ok (probably especially because of the song)

Comment: Another example in American English is that someone in a rural area would say either "we went to town" or "we went to the city", but not vice versa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In American English, we always use a determiner (or the plural) when going to hospitals or airports. The form with "the" is used for both cases where "the" makes sense, because you're talking about a particular one, and for the general sense you asked about: "the hospital", "the airport". So in your examples, you should say "took him to **the** hospital" and "be at **the** airport".

I've never heard "go to hospital" or "go to airport" in normal use*. While I could guess what meaning was intended, it doesn't truly have a meaning in my dialect.

When you use a language or dialect idiomatically, you don't always phrase things *exactly* the way you mean. Sometimes there's a more common phrasing, and you choose to rephrase what you're saying to use that more common phrasing. "The hospital" and "the airport" are phrases like that in American English. Even in cases where "go to a hospital" or "go to an airport" might make more sense, people will choose to say "the hospital" or "the airport".

<sub>* There are note-taking and headline-writing registers of American English where articles are commonly dropped out, so in those situations you'd find "go to airport", but that's an abbreviation of "go to the airport".</sub>

Comment: Are you saying that ‘‘the hospital’’ is (always) understood to mean a particular hospital?  If so, I disagree. I can say ‘‘I’ve been in the hospital three times this year.’’, and Americans will *not* necessarily understand that to mean that it was the same hospital all three times.

Comment: @Scott you're right, I agree. Not sure how to best explain that, I'll have to think (or maybe someone else can just write a better answer explaining this side of it?) It's similar to "the bathroom"; after a number of times in your life of going to **the** bathroom, it's no longer likely to be the same one. Maybe this just means that I'm wrong to say "it's not for general phenomena", and instead the situation is that we use the version with "the" for *both* the general and the specific.

Comment: I mentioned this in another comment to me, but you can see examples of "go to hospital" in US English at https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/ - which isn't to say it sounds natural to everyone, and "go to **the** hospital" is an order of magnitude more common, but it's definitely in popular use

Comment: @cactustictacs looking through the examples, most look like either UK/International English or broken English. Could you highlight some convincing examples of it being in popular use in US English?

Comment: Some of them are international (but present in US culture where the corpus is drawn from) but others are US magazines, news reports, TV shows, novels, movies, academic journals etc. And "broken English" is irrelevant when it's an actual example of the language in use. The phrasing is well represented ("go to **the** hospital" is 20x more frequent but it's a significant fraction) in the corpus which is specifically compiled to represent and analyse popular contemporary language in the US, so I'm not sure what else I can give you?

Comment: @cactustictacs you could give a good specific example. Or are you just trying to split hairs? Broken English is not irrelevant, especially on this site, and especially in fictional examples of broken English. You can see in my answer how I addressed a couple registers of English where the use of articles is abbreviated out. Maybe could say something similar about nonstandard American English, but I don't feel that's relevant enough (nor do I know enough to write about this).

Comment: @cactustictacs "but it's definitely in popular use" no, it really isn't.

Comment: I'm not here to debate whose use of English counts and whose doesn't, I'm just presenting a major academic source of US linguistic data that shows that the phrase is in use and represented to a significant degree. I mean if you have a better source of data then great, otherwise we're just having the usual "nobody says that" argument when it's just an example the OP used to ask a broader question

Comment: @cactustictacs I looked at the source you linked to. It did not look like it showed what you say it shows. But you could clarify that by giving specific examples.

Comment: You've seen them, you've personally decided they dont count and the corpus isn't representative for various reasons, I'm not interested in an argument with you about it

Comment: @cactustictacs I am not in your head, I do not know which ones you feel are representative. But I'm fine with not discussing this more if that's your preference.

Answer (score 24):

Your textbook, I'm afraid, is not accurate, or perhaps there has been a misunderstanding. American English is no different from its British cousin in the omission of articles for certain nouns which represent institutional locations (e.g. *school*, *jail*) or habitual activities and meals (e.g. *work*, *dinner*):

- at home
- in/to bed
- in/to town / port
- at/to work / sea
- in/at/to school / class / church / court / camp / chambers (of a judge) / prayers
- at/to practice / rehearsal / drill
- in/to hospital / prison / jail / detention

*Hospital* is not used in this way in American English; someone on a hospital stay is invariably *in the hospital* in AmE, even when not referring to any specific hospital, and regardless of how many hospitals it is possible for one to be at. This is comparable to saying one is going *to the store* or will be *in the office*.

For another example, baccalaureate-level education in the U.S. is known as *college* (regardless of the name or classification of the academic institution). As such, an undergraduate is away *at college* rather *at university*, with the latter sounding foreign or even pretentious.

There is no hard-and-fast rule about this, though I believe I have named the most common examples. Sometimes, this pattern is extended to related (or metaphorically related) concepts, but not always. One might be *in jail* or *in prison*. As a delinquent adolescent, one might have been *in [juvie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youth_detention_center)* (AmE) — but at no point would one be *in penitentiary*; it would have to be *in the penitentiary*.

Comment: It might also be, especially in (crime/gangster/noir) movies, "in _the_ pen" or "in stir". Or maybe "in lockup" but properly that's the short-term jail for suspects/defendants, not the long-term prison for convicts :-)

Comment: "They took him to a hospital. He is in the hospital." Note that "a hospital" is correct when talking about any hospital, whereas "in the hospital" is a specific idiom referring to the state of being hospitalized.

Comment: @shadowtalker it’s perfectly natural to say, “they took him to the hospital“. if someone said, “they took him to a hospital” i’d half expect to find out that the patient has been somehow misplaced or they’re deliberately keeping his location hidden from others.

Comment: @A.Ellett but "a local hospital" or "a nearby hospital" is common.

Comment: @shadowtalker i definitely concur if phrased that way. yes.

Comment: In BrE you *can* be "in hospital" or taken "to hospital". You cannot be "in airport" or "taken to airport" (those would require "the" or possibly "a"/"an"). I had thought I'd heard "in hospital" in AmE too, but am just a regular visitor not a native speaker of AmE.

Comment: You say “American English is no different from its British cousin in the omission of articles for certain nouns which represent institutional locations (e.g. *school*, *jail*) or habitual activities and meals (e.g. *work*, *dinner*)”, and then go on to cite a few exceptions.  I find this confusing; there *are* differences, so saying “X is no different from Y” is misleading at best.

Comment: Agreed with Scott, especially since the differences are idiosyncratic. "He's in hospital" is not typical AmE, though entirely understandable, but common in BrE, while "he's in jail" is just fine in AmE.

Comment: Interesting note: In Scottish Standard English "I took him to the hospital" is preferred over omitting "the", same as in the US generally. So perhaps don't just assume this is a "British" thing. It's not.

Comment: Re office: When it is used for "at work" one might say "in office" or "out of office"

Comment: @ljrk but, again, not in American English. In American English it’s more natural sounding to say “at the office” or “out of the office”. I think “in office” sounds strange but even if you said “in the office” it sounds like the *office* is something separate, like you might find in an autoshop.

Answer (score 7):

Best practice is something like this,

For a non-specific hospital (or you don't know which one):
"The took him to a hospital."

For a specific one (even if you only know the specific one in your head):
"They took him to the hospital."

Note that this is not a hard rule.  "The" can also be non-specific if you want.

What is never okay in American English (as opposed to British English):
"They took him to hospital."

Edit to address comments:

Yes, it is always "the airport," or "an airport."  Never "They took him to airport."

But user @Weather Vane has humbled me with an exception to the rule.  "Court".

"They took him to court to sue him," is correct in American English.
Amusingly, this only applies to legal courts.  Leading to the correct sentence, "They took him to court, then afterwards had a bite to eat at *the* food court, and saw a game at *a* basketball court."

And there are other exceptions, pointed out smartly in other answers.  So I can only say it usually a rule when talking about a place more than you are talking about an event.

Comment: What about the examples with "airport"? Is an article needed or not? And why?

Comment: What is **always** OK in British English: "They took him to hospital."

Comment: @Michael Harvey  Yes. And "I'm going to bed". My Glasgow friends often say, "I'm away to *my* bed." But see me? I don't care *whose* it is.

Comment: Does AmE never say "they took him to court"?

Comment: They took him to school.

Comment: They took him to task?

Answer (score 0):

I think going *to hospital* is a special case, in the same way you can go *to school*. It's less about a specific place than describing an action or state (like being *in hospital*) so you use that particular phrasing. But we don't have a similar understanding around airports or the concept of an airport, so that's just treated as a normal location and needs an determiner like *an* or *the*.

Comment: **to hospital** would sound incorrect to an American. You would say **to a hospital**.

Comment: This corpus of US English has plenty of examples of *to hospital*, *go to hospital* etc: https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/

Comment: While there are plenty of written examples for AmE of 'to hospital' (though at least some of them are from foreign characters in American literature), it quite simply is not idiomatic in modern vernacular in most parts of the US. It will usually be understood, but you'll sound a bit foreign (or possibly a bit pretentious) to most Americans if you use it.

Comment: Well sure, it might not be common, I'm just very wary of absolute statements like "nobody says this" when some do. But anyway, that's just an example the OP picked - you could have had "to school" which I'm assuming sounds more familiar and natural? The point really is there are some "places" that can also represent a concept instead of a specific location, and there are phrases around that which drop the determiner (which would normally be required) as a result

Comment: If you feel you've found examples of "to hospital" being idiomatic American English, [edit] your answer to quote some. No one's questioning "to school", but just like "to school" doesn't imply "to airport", "to school" doesn't imply "to hospital".

Comment: -1 ,  I have never heard a native speaker say " to hospital" unless they were trying to sound british.

Comment: Looking through the list in the corpus of US English, all the examples I saw were either people misclassified as US English (guest blog posts, quotes, comments, etc) or mistakes (use "the hospital" in a similar context elsewhere). It's possible that this is a feature of an obscure US dialect, but I don't think that link is good evidence for it.

Comment: @cactustictacs I would not rely on that website (corpus of US English), much of the content it refers to appears to be poorly written 'blogspam', which sounds like it was written by non-US English speakers.

Answer (score -1):

For completeness' sake (and a grin) another use of the "the" must be mentioned. Besides the correct use, that is. The likes of Kevin Pollak or Craig Ferguson, for instance, are deliberately calling a certain web service "The twitter". I'm pretty sure, they're not doing that by mistake... ;)

Comment: Calling it *The Twitter* is very common.  I thought everybody did it.

Comment: @Chenmunka Well, I guess "you had to be there". Usually, you would say for instance "I read on Twitter that..." when they would proclaim "I was reading on The Twitter that..." displaying not only a good amount of ironic distance (disguised as self-deprecation), but also -- at least with Pollak -- a special Jewish flavor of irony, I think. And as I'm writing this, I realize I am arguing humor. I shouldn't... Sorry. More to the point: I don't remember ever hearing "the twitter" in casual conversion -- let alone in writing. But honestly, what do I know? I live in Berlin...