# difference between "A" and "the" when talking about a race

Tags: grammar, articles

What is the difference between **A** and **The** in the following sentences?

- No other animal is as tall as **a/the** giraffe.
- ***An/the*** Inland Taipan's venom is the most venomous one in the world.

My grammar book says when we want to talk about a race or a whole class we use **the**. But still I am unable to decide **a** or **the** which one I should use. Can any please explain the meaning of each of the sentences using **a** and **the**. And which one do you think is more appropriate?

Comment: Related: [Uses of the definite article (the) in generic noun phrases](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/uses-of-the-definite-article-the-in-generic-noun-phrases)

Answer (score 1):

When we talk about *the giraffe* to refer to giraffes as a class, we are essentially talking about **a conceptual giraffe rather than a concrete giraffe**. It is referring to **the class itself**. Thus, we can say

> The giraffe evolved around one million years ago.

But we cannot say

> The giraffe would be a strange pet

At least, unless we're talking about a specific giraffe.

When we use the indefinite article, using *a giraffe* to talk in general terms, we are speaking of **an arbitrary giraffe**. It is a concrete giraffe, but it is **not a specific concrete giraffe**. Essentially, it means "**any given giraffe**". Thus, we can say:

> A giraffe would be a strange pet

But we cannot say

> A giraffe evolved around one million years ago

At least, not unless you have a funny idea of how evolution works - and even then you wouldn't be speaking in general terms any more.

In both of these cases, it's important to distinguish between the general, non-specific usage and the specific usage. Both *the* and *a* can be used when speaking of specific giraffes as well. The difference here is about how they are used to make general statements about non-specific giraffes.