# Usage of 'the' as to refer a species

Tags: grammar

Have I used **the** correctly as to refer a whole species?

- Like **the** ant, **the** bee lives in a group. Its nest is called a hive that is made of wax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uses of the definite article (the) in generic noun phrases](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/uses-of-the-definite-article-the-in-generic-noun-phrases)

Comment: Yes. So I think my sentence is correct. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

In a non-technical way, yes, except bees and ants are each made up of many species, and this usage refers (or can refer) to them all.

For example, the excellent set of series by the BBC (including Blue Planet and Planet Earth) uses this language, but David Attenborough (the narrator) is clearly going for the lay (non-expert) audience.

For a specific species, you wouldn't use "the" unless you also use species as part of it
- Homo sapiens was but one of many species of hominids around the Mediterannean Sea at the time ...
The species *Homo sapiens* ...
The *Homo sapiens* species ...