# a/the/no article, A computer is a

Tags: articles

I am struggling with English articles. Do these two sentences mean the same?

a) A computer is a useful machine in graphic design.

b) The computer is a useful machine in graphic design. (meaning all computers as a group, not one specific computer)

Comment: 'A computer' is OK, and 'the computer' is also OK, as explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/333481/article-usage-he-invented-the-slide-rule)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [article usage, He invented THE slide rule](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/333481/article-usage-he-invented-the-slide-rule)

Comment: Better than either would be "Computers are useful machines in graphic design"

Comment: The invented the slide rule. is not the same case as here.

Comment: @JamesK: It's neither better nor worse. "The computer is..." or "Computers are..." are both 100% equivalent for this purpose. "A computer is..." changes the feel of the sentence a tiny bit, but it's still 100% fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is one context where a/the have the same meaning.

- A computer is a useful machine in graphic design.
- The computer is a useful machine in graphic design.

Bear in mind, that generally speaking, those mean the same thing.

***HOWEVER,***  using **the** like that is considered formal English:

**The dog** is a noble beast.

I'll repeat that: generalities in English are usually expressed with the determiner a or a plural noun.

- A dog is a noble beast. [generality, standard]
- Dogs are noble beasts. [generality, standard]
- The dog is a noble beast. [generality, formal]

Comment: If you reversed the first two phrasings in your final set of three, they'd be in *rising* order of "formality".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree with you.

Comment: The guy down the pub probably wouldn't say his dog was a "noble beast" anyway, so we're already in a relatively raised register. But imho *A pig is a dirty animal* is a lot more "formal / declamatory" than *Pigs are dirty animals* in the context of "pub talk".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Really, pub talk? How about: two Cambridge or Oxford professors waxing lyrical over a whiskey?